# how to split a string of text into 2 columns in python

Tags: python, string, split, sentence

I am struggling to split the string of a file text into 2 separated columns.
After I split text into sentences

```
for s in sentences:
    row = s.strip()            
    print(row)
```

it provides me this output in the same column:

```
['1'
 "It is hands-down the best sporting museum in Australia
The kids (and dad) loved the interactive sports section
The amount of Olympic memorabilia was outstanding    
Don't miss going to this iconic venue."]
['2'
 "...
  ..."]
```

The output expected:

```
No     sentences
1     It is hands-down the best sporting museum in Australia
1     The kids (and dad) loved the interactive sports section
1     The amount of Olympic memorabilia was outstanding    
1     Don't miss going to this iconic venue.
2     ...
2     ...
```

Anyone has any ideas, please help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: It's not `strip`, it's `split` here

Comment: if might be helpful, if you add content of the file or what's there in `sentences`

Comment: @U9-Forward: Thanks for your answer, it I use 'split', it would provide the output like this: ["Don't", 'miss', 'going', 'to', 'this', 'iconic', 'venue."], and this is not what I expect.

Comment: @user3713719: the sentences is the paragraph like above, and I wanna break it into sentences as shown above.

Comment: @Julie My answer?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like, got `sentences` as something like:

```
sentences=[['1','foobar'],['2','blahblah']]
```

So then try:

```
print('\n'.join(['\t'.join(i) for i in sentences]))
```